# При открытии файла с помощью Atom и пакета script появляется ошибка

Tags: windows-10, atom

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При запуске обычного хелоуворлд файла в Атоме при помощи пакета script, консоль отображает "сломанную" ошибку. Такая ошибка появляется при запуске любого файла(в том числе и пустого) на любом языке.

Что я сделал не так и в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил свой вопрос и это было элементарно.
Суть заключается в том, чтобы запускать Атом через консоль, а не напрямую через .exe файл, потому что так Атом не видит переменные в `PATH`.